# includesvg does not scale the svg file properly in overleaf

Tags: graphics, svg

I created an svg file in lucid chart and exported it to overleaf. I used the following code to load the svg picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{"getdents interception.svg"}
    \caption{\textbf{\textit{getdents}} interception}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

After compiling the output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the picture is not scaled correctly. I have included both graphicx and 
svg package. What am I doing wrong here?

[**Link to overleaf project**](https://www.overleaf.com/6947841417bdzkpbjhbwny)

Comment: Please do not post links to code, in particular when they are password protected.

Comment: I couldn't post the svg picture here. So I posted a link to the lucid chart document. Let me fix it.

Comment: I've fixed the link. Can you access it now? @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: No, I can't, but more importantly most users do not *want* to follow external links, for obvious reasons.

Comment: How can I share the svg image then? I tried posting it but imgur won't let me.

Comment: you could make a public project in overleaf with the svg, but try putting `\fbox{\incluesvg...}` if the white space is inside the box, then your svg has white space and it is text width but white at the edges, you could crop it in svg or when you export it originally

Comment: I've posted a link to an overleaf project @DavidCarlisle

Comment: fbox clearly indicates there's whitespace, but when I download the svg from lucid chart I choose "crop to content" so that there's no unnecessary whitespace. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Have you already tried scaling? `\includesvg[scale=0.8]{interception.svg}`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I also made a figure on lucidchart. Did you find a solution?